# Are holograms in midair physically possible?

Tags: visible-light, hologram

Is it possible for holograms, as in 3D projections of light in midair, to exist? [image]

Consider this image. If a projector, placed in the same position as the gray circle in the first image, were to project some sort of light into the air, would it be able to form a three-dimensional image such as this bowl?

Comment: on what will the projector project? I alway found this to be an astonishingly real looking arial image: https://www.exploratorium.edu/snacks/parabolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is about holograms per se, the answer is "no": The image displayed by a hologram is always between the observer and the hologram, or else the hologram is between the observer and the image (like a window).

But if the question is about the possibility of projecting a 3D image into mid-air without anything the observer must look through or against, then the answer is "yes".  I know of one approach, which is to use a laser with sufficient power to ionize the air at a focal point, causing the air to glow.  The focal point can be scanned to draw a 3D image.  [This kind of image](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/consumer-electronics/audiovideo/femtosecond-lasers-create-3d-midair-plasma-displays-you-can-touch) is visible from all directions.